# Consumir Api de Rick and Morty!

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola buenas tardes tengo una pequeña duda intento consumir api pero no puedo ver que se vea en mi template, pero con otra si funciona

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Api</h1>
    <ul v-if="characters">
        <li v-for="character in characters" :key="character.id" :name="character.name">
            <h3>{{ character.name}}</h3>
        </li>            
    </ul>       
</div>
```

```
<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
export default {
    name: 'Characters',
    setup() {
        const characters = ref(null)
        onMounted(async () => {
        const response = await fetch ("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"); // no funciona
        // const response = await fetch ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"); // si funciona
            characters.value = await response.json();            
        })
        return {characters}
    },
}
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria solucionar esto

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu problema esta en como accedes a los datos del json, en la primera imagen los datos que te interesan ya vienen en la raiz del json, pero en la segunda imagen los datos que te interesan se encuentran en el objeto `results`, por lo que debes moverte hacia allí

```
<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
export default {
    name: 'Characters',
    setup() {
        let characters = ref(null)
        onMounted(async () => {
        const response = await fetch ("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"); // no funciona
            characters = await response.json()       
        })
        return {characters.results}
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: me da error con el return {characters.results} me dice: Parsing error: Unexpected token .

Comment: lo que hice fue en mi ciclo poner esto:
v-for="character in characters.results" :key="character.id"
así me funciono!